# Restarting a c# TopShelf service programmatically

Tags: c#, topshelf

I find myself in a terrible situation where I have a topshelf service that uses a c++ library with memory issues. Because of this obination of a place I find myself in, I want to call TopShelf to restart the service every now and then during a pause in it's activities for no other reason but to "make the world right again".

Are there any TopShelf APIs that allow for this? I cannot seem to find any in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

call `Environment.Exit(1);` when u want restart service

then in HostFactory add Enable ServiceRecovery

```
HostFactory.Run(configure =>
            {
                configure.Service((ServiceConfigurator<Service> service) =>
                {

                    service.WhenStarted(s => s.Start());
                    service.WhenStopped(s => s.Stop());
                });

                //Setup Account that window service use to run.  
                configure.RunAsNetworkService();
                configure.SetServiceName("ServiceName");
                configure.SetDisplayName("ServiceName");
                configure.SetDescription("Description");
                configure.StartAutomaticallyDelayed();
                configure.EnableServiceRecovery(recoveryOption =>
                {
                    recoveryOption.RestartService(0);
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure Topshelf doesn't support this so you would have to do this from code yourself.

Take a look at the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class.

Worst case you could have a second simple topshelf installer that manages your current service and restarts it? (bit dirty i know)

Comment: TopShelf does support - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53648288/4039094